# Borel measure on unit sphere of infinite dimension

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $C[0,1]$ be the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, and endow it with the sup-norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $S=\{u\in C[0,1]\mid \|u\|=1\}$ be the unit sphere of $C[0,1]$ (endowed with the relative norm topology). Does there exist a Borel probability measure on $S$? What if $S$ is instead endowed with the weak topology?

Comment: What about the Dirac measure sitting at $\bar u$, where $\bar u$ is your favorite element of $S$?

Answer (score 1):

Topologically, the unit sphere in $C[0,1]$ with the norm topology is second-countable and metrisable, i.e. Polish. As such, from measure-theoretic perspective, it is just an uncountable standard Borel space, indistinguishable from the unit interval, and as such, holds a multitude of probability Borel measures, and moreover,  they are all very well-behaved with respect to the topology (i.e. regular).

With the weak topology, the picture is probably not that clean, but I believe that if you intersect the sphere with a finite-dimensional subspace, you get something homeomorphic to an $S^n$ (the weak topology is just the norm topology on finite-dimensional subspaces), and thus you can certainly find lots of measures concentrated on those.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\nu$ be any Borel probability measure on $C[0,1]$ that puts no mass on the zero function, and take $\mu$ to be the image of $\nu$ under the mapping $C[0,1]\ni x\mapsto(x(t)/\|x\|: 0\le t\le 1)\in S$.